# How to split a string (of arguments) in fish?

Tags: linux, shell, fish

I want to split `"-r --run"` into `"-r"` and `"--run"`

for

```sh
string split " " "-r --run"
```

I get

> string split: -r --run: unknown option` as an error

It is mistaking the string for flags. How do I make it treat it as a string to split?

Comment: You might be interested in what `$ man getopt` tells you.

Comment: I'd remove the `linux` tag, because fish is available for macOS, BSD and Windows as well (https://fishshell.com/#platform_tabs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`string` docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string.html) say:

> Arguments beginning with `-` are normally interpreted as switches; `--` causes the following arguments not to be treated as switches even if they begin with `-`.

So the command is:

```sh
  string split -- " " "-r --run"
```

Comment: This is... interesting from the POV of the ban on chatGPT.  The answer is perfectly correct, chatGPT gave it to you, and you cite your source whilst self-answering.  I've not authority here whatsoever but if I *did* I think I'd think it was fine.  But it it's interesting, as the first *decent* answer I've seen involving GPT.  FWIW the `--` convention for separating args from commands is very common: I'm surprised nobody suggested it earlier.

Comment: I would say chatGPT mention should not be considered as source here (it's about the same as saying "it appeared to me in dream") and may be even removed. The answer itself is fine and just reproducible example with demonstrated result should be enough.

Comment: According to the [string docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string.html), the options are intended to appear before the separator. `string split -- " " $s`

Comment: I felt free to edit this answer, replacing the ChatGPT citation by the fish docs. Also, I put `--` before the separator, making it look more clear (so that the `--` comes before _all_ non-switch arguments).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it would be:

```
echo "--r -run" | string split " "
```

So piping the string into that command.